# firefox.tmp in ~/Download Folder

Tags: firefox, snap

Since I use Firefox as Snappacket, a "firefox.tmp" always appears in the download directory. In this directory other directories are created such as: Temp-0955e731-4e34-44bc-b9cf-7e6526711a73. When i open/close Firefox the Temp-Dir will delete/created and so on. Is there any way to stop this forever or at least move it to /tmp? SSDs have a limited read and write time and the download directory is unnecessarily cluttered. Hardlinks doesnt work. I already move the Cache to /tmp (browser.cache.disk.parent_directory). By the way, the same happens with Snap-Thunderbird.

Comment: Not really sure this is a significant problem to be seriously concerned with these days. [This reference](https://linustechtips.com/topic/811454-should-i-be-worried-of-ssd-write-limit/) provides a useful resource.

Comment: An explanation for this unfortunate behavior is here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/xdg-open-not-working-on-firefox/17670/14 It would require changing the `$TMPDIR` folder in the environment of the snap if that is possible without repackaging the snap, and still, the folder should be in a location where the snap version has access.

Comment: Is all that snap complexity worthwhile? I feel like I prefer good all systems. I struggle to find things that were very organized, easy and fast earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hide this folder by

```
cd Download
echo 'firefox.tmp' >> .hidden
```

Comment: This is an interesting work around, but does not work if one (like me) sets the preference that hidden files are always shown.

Answer (score 0):

This folder only gets created with the snap installation of Firefox. Alternatively you can install it by downloading the .tar file from the [website](https://www.mozilla.org/de/firefox/new/)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put something like this in a script that you run on session start:

```
(tmp="$HOME/Downloads/firefox.tmp"; 
 while true; do
   if [ -f "$tmp" ]; then
     rm -rf "$tmp";
   fi;
   sleep 30;
   done) &
```

A slightly more sophisticated version would have the script also check for the pid of its session or window manager and exit if that process goes away.  Otherwise, repeated login/logout may leave multiple such scripts running (messy, but not damaging by itself).